# Ext object has no method require

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.window.Window'
]);
```

On above line, I am getting the error: Object has no method require. The whole source is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all.js"></script>
  <title>Title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'ext/resources/images/default/s.gif';
  Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.window.Window'
    ]);
  Ext.onReady(function() {
    console.log(Ext);
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you including Ext 4? Because Ext4 doesn't have any adapters, that something in older versions.

Comment: The Ext JS tutorials of different versions are pretty confusing. Can you be more specific about which version should I use.

Comment: Use the latest version. The examples show you what you need to include.